# Are there any resumé revision services available for PhD applicants?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, cv

I am preparing a resumé for a PhD application. I'd like to know if there any good, and not necessarily free, services that evaluate and comment on a resumé.

Comment: If you are currently a student , your university career services can help.

Comment: Ask the faculty who are writing your recommendation letters. They'll have the clearest idea what you should include, because they're the ones actually reading PhD applications.

Comment: By the way, I can't imagine it would be worth paying for CV advice for a PhD application.  For ordinary job searches, people sometimes pay for resume advice because they want to do whatever they can to minimize the chances that their resume will be tossed aside after a quick glance.  That's not really how PhD admissions works, the CV plays a less central role, and in any case it's easier to write an academic CV than a resume (it's more comprehensive and thus involves less choice, and you don't have to sell things as hard).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, literally hundreds. Have you googled something like "professional resume for phd application" or "professional resume writing services"? You are bound to find something near where you live, including quite possibly your undergrad university.

The big question, I think, is whether for a PhD application you should be supplying a ***resume*** or a ***curriculum vitae***? CV's are usually more common for academic and research positions. If you are unsure about the differences, here are a [couple](http://www.grad.illinois.edu/careerservices/cvorresume) of [useful](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/curricula-vitae-cvs-versus-resumes/) links.

Good luck with the application.